# How to make webservice accessible publicly?

Tags: java, host

I have java web service presently running on my localhost. I want to make it accessible over internet so that anybody can access it.

I want to self host my web service.(i.e I don't want to use any hosting provider)

I want to make it accessible by my private IP address or public IP address(i.e I don't need DNS service provider).

I have LAN connection.

Please describe every step
Thank's in advanced

Answer (score 0):

If you have static IP for your home computer from your ISP than anyone can make a hit from internet to your webservice using your static IP.

Static IP identifies your computer over the internet distinctly.

First from different network try to ping your machine using static IP even try to run a web server temporarily to check if its accessible through static IP.

**Just need to make sure that required port for your application is opened to be accessible from internet if its web server or application server.**

Once its accessible than you can run a server in your machine and deploy your web services on the server to access it.

Answer (score 0):

To identify PC on the internet we need static IP.

Acquiring a Static IP or dynamic DNS for your Network

If dealing with dynamic IP addresses sounds like one big headache, there's another type of address: the static IP. A static IP does not change. You can request a static IP address from your ISP, usually for an additional fee, and only if the ISP offers static IPs to its customers. Another option is to use a dynamic DNS service. DNS stands for domain name system, and a dynamic DNS gives a permanent domain name to a computer, such as mybusiness.ddns.com, and automatically keeps track of that computer's IP address, even if it changes. Therefore, when someone on the outside internet wants to contact your computer, they can contact mybusiness.ddns.com, and the dynamic DNS service will know how to contact your computer. It's like having a personal assistant whose job it is to know how to reach you at all times.

1. Get your Static IP Address (it can be accessible over internet).
2. Install Server that supports HTTP Protocol like Apache server on it.
3. Create an account with Free DNS Server (if required) like https://now-ip.com/
4. Configure the server with your Static IP and also make sure your firewall settings to not to avoid inbound traffic from internet.
5. Deploy your web service with the Port number in the server.
6. Try to ping the same from other internet PC.